# transfer (add/remove) php array values between 2 divs

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, search

I have a normal div, having an input textbox which can be edited manually.
I want to add/remove php values from another div having a set of php array values (from a query). Each value have an [Add] or a [Remove] button that is based on weather the corresponding php value exists in the input text field or not.

So, basically if the textbox is empty, then all the buttons will be [Add] and clicking it will add the corresponding php value to the textbox, and then change into a [Remove] button. Likewise, any [Remove] button will remove the corresponding php value from the textbox, and then change into an [Add] button.

> EXAMPLE:
>  $values = array("**Mike**", "**James**", "**Jerry**", "**Tom**");
>  input type="text"

If I manually made any changes to the textbox or entered some known php values into it (separated by a semi-colon):

> **James;Mike;Hyde;Jerry;**

The other div will dynamically search for all the values of the php array and add a [Remove] button for the ones that exist, and an [Add] button for those who were not found in the textbox.

James [**Remove**]
Mike [**Remove**]
Tom [**Add**]
Jerry [**Remove**]

> Notice #1: Here, '**Tom**' is the only value that do not exist in the
>   textbox, so it has a [Remove] button.
> Notice #2: Also, '**Hyde**'
>   is not known as a value of the php array, so it has neither an [Add]
>   nor a [Remove] button.

---

### **Edit:**

What I already did, is basically echo all array values from the php query and attach each with an [Add] button (since the textbox is empty by default)
I'm using custom js functions similer to:

> $("#textbox").val(function(i, val) {   return
>   val.replace(phparrayvalue, ''); });

But, in order to dynamically change the buttons between [Add] and [Remove], I'll have to keep the php array all the time (AJAX requests will be slow to get the php values ontextchange).
**I think the problem would vanish if I could pass and convert the php array into a javascript one** onload. After that it would be easy to compare the saved js array with the textbox value ontextchange, and change buttons based on the result.

I hope it is clear and someone can help with the javascript code.
*Thank you*

Comment: Right now this is a "gimme the codez" demand. Show what you've attempted so far, show that you've put at least SOME effort into trying this yourself. With that, we'll try to help. But right now, voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I properly understood your question, this may help

### Preview:

[image]

Create simple html document for testing..

### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Test Add/Remove</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="adddel.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
  body { font-family: tahoma, verdana, arial; }
  .btn { color: #0000ff; font-size: 12px; cursor: pointer; }
  .div1 { width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #ffffee; border: dashed 1px #494949; position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px; padding: 10px; }
  .div2 { width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #ffffee; border: dashed 1px #494949; position: absolute; left: 280px; top: 50px; padding: 10px; font-size: 14px; }
  .myinput { width: 194px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; border: solid 1px #000000; padding: 3px; }
  -->
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divinput" class="div1"></div>
  <div id="divvalues" class="div2"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  // echo next line from php code
  myArray = 'Mike,James,Jerry,Tom';

  jsStart(myArray, 'divinput', 'divvalues');
  -->
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Like you can see, this html contains **title**, link to external **JavaScript** file and some **style** for page elements in **HEAD** part, and two **DIVs** and some simple **on-page JavaScript** in **BODY** part.

All you have to do is to create JavaScript variable **myNames** from PHP code. I've used same names you mentioned in question so my line looks like this:

```
myArray = 'Mike,James,Jerry,Tom';
```

Create comma-separated list in PHP and **echo** it here.

Behind that line I called function **jsStart()** which is defined in external JavaScript file **adddel.js**.

Let see how that file looks like

### adddel.js

```
var name = Array();

// page preparation
function jsStart(a, div1id, div2id) {
  // create array of names
  name = a.split(',');
  // create div1 html
  html = '<input type="text" name="myedit" id="myedit" class="myinput" value="" onchange="changeText()" onkeyup="changeText()">';
  document.getElementById(div1id).innerHTML = html;
  // create div2 html
  html = '';
  for (i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
    if (name[i].trim() != '') {
      if (html != '') html += '<br />';
      // name
      html += '&bull; <b>' + name[i] + '</b> ';
      // button
      html += ' <span class="btn" id="btn' + i + '" onclick="btnClick(' + i + ')">[Add]</span>';
      }
    }
  if (html == '') html = '&nbsp;';
  document.getElementById(div2id).innerHTML = html;
  changeText();
  }

// fires on input-text change
function changeText() {
  edl = document.getElementById('myedit').value.trim().split(';'); 
  for (i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
    btnText = '[Add]';
    for (j=0; j<edl.length; j++) {
      ne = name[i].trim().toLowerCase();
      nl = edl[j].trim().toLowerCase();
      if (ne == nl) {
        btnText = '[Remove]';
        break;
        }
      }
    document.getElementById('btn' + i).innerHTML = btnText;
    }
  }

// add/remove name from text-input
function btnClick(id) {
  ne = name[id].trim().toLowerCase();
  edl = document.getElementById('myedit').value.trim().split(';'); 
  newed = '';
  found = false;
  for (i=0; i<edl.length; i++) {
    nl = edl[i].trim().toLowerCase();
    if (nl != '') {
      if (nl != ne) newed += edl[i].trim() + ';';
      else found = true;
      }
    }
  if (!found) newed+=name[id]+';'
  document.getElementById('myedit').value = newed;
  changeText();
  }
```

Place both files in same directory and open **test.html** file from your browser. If you did it right you'll have something like picture at the top of my post.

**Note: items in text-input are case-insensitive and additional spaces around names are allowed.**

That means text

```
"Mike;John;Sam; BRian"
```

is same as

```
"   mike ; john;Sam;Brian "
```

Now edit this code and make it fits your needs. Simple as it is.

### Hope this helps

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

For the kind of thing that you are trying to do, have you considered "Chosen" ?
Here is a link to it:
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

It will alove you to do precisly what you are trying to do, albeit in a much more elegant way.
You can pass your list of names from your PHP array into the plugin and it can take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot, karancan. I'll check it out and get back to you.